# How to push_back a bidimesional array?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stdvector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

int main() {
int A[6][6];

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j <6; j++){
        A[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

A[0][1] = 1;
A[0][3] = 1;
A[1][2] = 1;
A[1][4] = 1;
A[2][4] = 1;
A[3][1] = 1;
A[4][3] = 1;
A[4][5] = 1;
A[5][2] = 1;

vector< vector< int > >;
A[0].push_back(1);
}
```

I'm trying to do an adjacency matrix from a graph. My professor gave me this code, but it has too many errors and I had never worked with `vector <vector < int > >`. The errors that the compiler give me are the following:

```
26  2 [Error] declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
27  7 [Error] request for member 'push_back' in 'A[0]', which is of non-class type 'int [6]'
```

Comment: You can't `push_back` into C-style array, and that's what your `A[0]` is.

Comment: I suspect you need to use either an *array* **or** a *vector* but not both.

Comment: It's still an array: `int A[6][6];`

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you expect `vector<vector<int>>;` to do?

Comment: I'm trying to store the data from that position of the array into the vector

Comment: @DanielRodríguez There is no "the" vector. As the compiler says, `vector<vector<int>>;` does not declare anything. It's just a type; it's like writing `int;`

Comment: When you declare a variable, most of the time you need to give it a name. Otherwise you can have a temporary variable, a variable around for so short a period of time that it doesn't need a name and has  restrictions on how it is used. Kind of odd how useful they are even with the restrictions, mind you. This isn't a temporary variable, though. You'd need some brackets for that.

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** use `push_back()` to an array (`A`). You need to create a vector (`B`) to use `push_back()`:

```
vector < vector < int > > B (6);

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j <6; j++){
        B[i].push_back(A[i][j]);
    }
}
```

To print `B`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j <6; j++){
        std::cout << B[i][j] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
0 1 0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 1 
0 0 1 0 0 0
```